# Qatar-India Codeshare flight DEL-DOH-WAW

Tags: luggage, check-in, qatar-airways, code-share, indigo

I have booked Qatar airways fligt from DEL-DOHA and then from DOHA-Warsaw with 3 hour layover in between. Even though both flights are of Qatar airways, the website says DEL-DOH is operated by Indigo.

My question is, if i check in at delhi do i need to checkin again at Doha or will I get my luggage directly in warsaw?

Comment: If it's booked as a single ticket, you will almost certainly check in for both flights at Delhi and your luggage will be checked through.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single booking made on Qatar, your bags will be checked through

See https://www.qatarairways.com/en/partners-codeshare.html and https://www.goindigo.in/baggage/baggage-transfer.html

This being said, nothing is ever 100% guaranteed. If there is any exception (very unlikely), they will tell you at check-in when you drop the bags and 3 hours is plenty.

The related question here would be if you have to enter Qatar and, if yes, what documentation you would need. You can put all your specific information in here to check it out: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm.

You should be fine, but it doesn't harm to double check.